# LMMS Sound Distorted

Tags: sound, 15.04, lmms

I downloaded lmms on to my ubuntu 15.04 system and I started to try to use it, but once I started, all the sounds in LMMS were all distorted and not sounding right. Some even had NO sound. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Have you experimented with different audio interfaces and/or buffer sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using jackd? If so, try increasing the frames per period. Also, if you're not using low latency kernel, try it. Make sure the sample rate is set appropriately.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToJACKConfiguration